# Error with create tables in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am learning sqlite3 in python3. I have added 4 columns in my table using the syntax

```
c.execute("CREATE table raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)")
```

and I want to insert values for them  so I am writing

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO raman VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')");
```

After this if I print the table its not showing me the inserted values. I am using this command to print        print c.execute("SELECT * FROM SQLITE_ master type='table'").fetchall()

Comment: Make sure you do: `[your connection object here].commit()` after inserting

Comment: This does not sound like an error but unintended results.

Comment: connection object means ?? And I am writing in a editor.

Answer (score 0):

The complete (minimal) sequence is this.

```
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("CREATE table raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000000000296E490>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO raman VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')"); 
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000000000296E490>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM raman'):
...     row
... 
(1, 'H', 1, 1)
```

Until you issue the **`commit`** the values won't be (or won't necessarily be) present in the table.

Comment: What I am doing is , I have made separate .py file to insert values. So there I have.                      import sqlite                                                       conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')
c = conn.cursor()                        c.execute("CREATE table raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)")

c.execute("INSERT INTO raman VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')");                                                                                  conn.commit()

Comment: When I print this it shows me this :                          [ ]

Comment: I tried in terminal also still it is printing [ ]. But I want to see the values which I am inserting

Comment: I cannot tell what might be wrong. I've edited the code in my answer to show what's put in the table.

Comment: What are you printing, exactly?

Comment: I am printing my table. So i want to print those values which I am inserting in rhe table

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How does that differ from what the code above shows?

Comment: I am sorry . that's working now in terminal. If I want to work with .py then its not working

Comment: No worries. Can you submit another question with the details?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400162/error-with-create-tables-in-sqlite3-in-editor/44400350#44400350                                                             I have posted a new one