# Error with create tables in sqlite3 in editor

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am creating table in my database. I am also inserting values into that table. So I am running the .py file in terminal it is not printing the inserted values. Its working in shell but with editor it doesn't ? I am writing this code to create table:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE table raman(ATOMIC NUMBER INT, SYMBOL TEXT, ROW INT , COLUMN INT)")

c.execute("INSERT INTO raman VALUES(1,'H',1,'1')");  

conn.commit()
```

Now if i want to print those inserted values it doesn't work in editor. but with shell its working. i am writing this to print :

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('raman.db')

c = conn.cursor()  

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM raman'):

       conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please tell us which line of the code is supposed to print the values.

Comment: in the shell it looks like this  https://pastebin.com/FCytBafN

Answer (score 0):

The `python` command-line shell prints out the value of everything you enter, but that is just intended for debugging.

To actually print something, use `print`:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM raman'):
    print row
```

(And you might want to extract the four values from the row and format them differently.)

Answer (score -1):

I see here  a few problems:

- At line 1 there is no closing parenthesis.
- At line 4 you are using single quotes inside the double quotes literal.